# Swing controls issue

Tags: java, swing

I have written one swing application.
I am using JTree,JComboBox,JPopup menu controls.
The problem I am facing is ,whenever I have select a value from combo,after the combo items state changed functionality completed then its setting the selected value to the combo.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6VSm.png]

here tf2.dell.com should be shown in the combo box as selected as soon as I have selected the value but its not happening immediately

Comment: Sounds like you're blocking the Swing Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) with your functionality. I recommend delegating any heavy logic to an `.invokeLater` call which means the UI is then free to update in a timely manner. We also can't see any of your code, so this is purely guesswork. I recommend posting any relevant code for people to read through.

Answer (score 1):

I think the operation performed on selection of combo value takes longer which affects the painting (Which is done by EDT aka Event Dispatcher Thread). The below code would help to run the heavy weight logic as a separate thread.

```
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    performOperationonSelect(selected);
                }
          });
```

Comment: In java 8: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> performOperationonSelect(selected));` where `selected` maybe made `final`.

Comment: I am directly adding my code under JComboBoxItemStateChanged() private void jComboBoxTFS_URLItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {

Comment: I am having 50controls.Do I need to use invokeLater() in all the events??private void jComboBoxTFS_URLItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {

 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                   ---my logic----
                }
          });
}...like this??and is the new thread will be closed once the my logic executed??

Comment: @suma2020 It depends on operations performed when the event occurs. if i would have design this kind of UI i would use invokeLater only if the operation performed takes more time and i would think of using some pattern to avoid boilerplate code. Again with lambda expression it would be single line of code as Joop Eggen mentioned in the comment.